# Proving $T^{n} \in \mathcal{L}(V, V), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$. Then we define the map $T^{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ recursively by

$$T^{1} = T$$
$$T^{k+1} = T \circ T^{k}$$

for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

How would I go about proving that $T^{n} \in \mathcal{L}(V, V), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ using induction?

I know that from the given definition of the map $T^{n}$ that $T^{i} = T \circ T^{i - 1}$. But I am not sure where/how exactly to start the proof.

Comment: $\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}$Can you first of all show that if $A,B\in \L(V,V)$, then $AB\in \L(V,V)$ (where $AB$ means $A\circ B$)? You effectively have to show that a composition of two linear maps is a linear map. Once you manage to show this, the induction should be fairly easy. A hint to show this: what does it mean for $AB$ to be in $\L(V,V)$, i.e. what are the conditions that must be satisfied? How can we use the assumptions that $A$ and $B$ are in $\L(V,V)$ to show that these conditions hold?

Comment: Can you tell us what $V$ is and what $\mathcal L(V,V)$ is? In particular it is important to know if $V$ is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $T^1$ is simply $T$, which is linear.

And, is $T^n$ is linear, then $T^{n+1}$ is linear too, because it is the composition of two linear maps (it is equal to $T\circ T^n$).